# Struts2 checkbox tree structure?

Tags: html, jsp, struts2

I need to make a tree structure with my JSP Code.

In the data taken from a database, there's a *parent* field which should identify the child nodes; I use the

```html
<s:iterator value="Activities"> 
    <s:property value="idActivity" />  
    <s:property value="name" />
    <s:property value="parent" />
</s:iterator>
```

Any ideas? I tried to use dynatree Library from GoogleCode but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If by *tree structure* you mean a tree-like indentation, just use `<ul>` and `<li>`.

Also pay attention to the list you're iterating, that should start with a lowercase letter:

```xml
<ul>
  <s:iterator value="activities"> 
    <li>
      <s:property value="idActivity" />  
      <s:property value="name" />
      <s:property value="parent" />
    </li>
  </s:iterator>
</ul>
```

BTW the question is very unclear, and it doesn't involve any checkbox. Try to be more specific next time (or this one, if this answer is not the one you're looking for)

Comment: yes i mean that, but i would like make something that when you check on node, automatically checks the child nodes

Comment: Then you should show some effort. Try to do it, then try again, then when you're really stuck, come back here and ask a question about the specific problem that did stop you. This is not that *"write the code for me while I get payed"* kind of site